# How to generate HTML with FluentMark

Tags: eclipse, markdown

I use Eclipse as IDE and I installed FluentMark from the Eclipse Market Place.

Afterwards, I wrote two MarkDown files which should be converted to HTML files. (It is the documentation of a bigger project.)

My question now is: how can I convert the .md files to HTML files without leaving Eclipse?

I set Eclipse to use Pandoc as converter with the path to the executable.

The problem now is: the conversion is not done automatically and I cannot find a button to do so. Building the project or Buiding all projects doesn't help.

How can I do this task?

I am relatively new to Eclipse, so I don't know all its features (yet).

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy to miss, new toolbar item "Export as HTML".
There is also an "Export as PDF" but it requires additional tools that can not be installed from Eclipse Marketplace.

I raised an issue with FluentMark about this unintuitive use.
https://github.com/grosenberg/fluentmark/issues/39

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are using FluentMark editor to edit the files.

While you are editing the files you can open 'FluentMark View' in Eclipse.
(You will have to choose 'Eclipse' -> 'Window' -> 'Show View'  and select 'FluentMark View' probably from the Other option if not already listed in the options to choose.)

This will give a real time view of how the markdown files would look, upon saving the file, Eclipse should have generated a hidden html file in the same folder as your markdown file exists.
For e.g., if I am editing a `README.md` then after saving it and viewing in 'FluentMark View' there is a hidden html file created in same directory as `.README.md.html`

If this isn't working you may also try choosing other 'Show View' options like 'GFM View' (if that is already preinstalled else look for it in Marketplace).

Comment: At least in the current version this kind of shadow files  doesn't (or no longer) exist.

Comment: The Eclipse live-view "FluentMark View" has been replaced by a website opened in the default browser, see https://github.com/grosenberg/Fluentmark/issues/58#issuecomment-794905213